# Server side redirection and Client side redirection in JSP - Which is better?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there any reason to believe Server-side redirection is better than Client side? Is server-side redirection more secure? I know server-side redirection is used in Multi-stage processing of data. But is it possible to use that instead of client-side redirection just for a page redirect(not multi-stage processing)?

Comment: server side redirection ? you mean forward ?

Comment: server side (or forwarding) can only be done to other resources on the same server whereas client side (or redirection) can be done to any other site.

Comment: Yes, in multi-stage processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, I would suggest to go for server side redirection because the server is responsible for every action that happens in the application.This way you will get more control over sensitive data.If your data is very sensitive then, preferably go for server side redirection as you will get a chance to sanitize your input.